# Want to burn Ubuntu as a disk so that my laptop that lacks an OS can run it from my external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

My laptop currently does not have an OS, I used to run Ubuntu 10.10 back in the day, then converted to Windows 7, but recently had to wipe my hard drive and want to try out Ubuntu 13.10. I have tried downloading the zip from the Ubuntu website, then extracting it to my external hard drive, but my laptop will not run Ubuntu from that. how can I convert it into a format that a computer with no operating system will read it? Some sort of disk file type, perhaps? Help!

Comment: where did you download the ubuntu.zip file?

Comment: the Ubuntu website.

Comment: plz provide the link.

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: but it ask me to download ubuntu.iso file.

Comment: did you want to burn the iso file to disk or usb?

Answer (score 0):

Simply copying the files to a drive will not work! You need to use an ISO image writing application (Windows 7 has one built in). You'll then have to enter your BIOS and make sure your external HDD is selected as a boot option.

EDIT: This will only work if you're burning to a CD/DVD. If you want to burn to a flash drive, take a look at http://www.pendrivelinux.com/. You'll probably have to do this first, then install onto your external HDD during installation. You can do this when it asks you about partitioning (select "something else" I think).

Comment: What is that writing application called?

Comment: From memory, it's something like 'Windows Disk Image Burner'. It should open automatically when you double click on the .iso file (unless you have other image burning apps installed).